# Why was $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n+1 = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$ cancelled this way?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a Youtube video explaining induction the teacher cancelled this:

$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n+1 = \frac{(n+1)(n+1+1)}{2}$$

This way:

$$\frac{n}{2}+1 = \frac{n+2}{2}$$

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6W4hIANEyVY (min 7:40)

I did the calculations and it is ok, it is just that the way he sees how to cancel right away what makes me wonder what property I am missing.

Comment: Notice that $n+1$ is a factor of both $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $n+1$. Thus he sees that every term has a factor of $n+1$ in common

Comment: I'm not sure this is what one calls "cancelling."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, in the given equality, we can factorize LHS as follows $$LHS=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n+1$$
$$=\frac{n(n+1)+2(n+1)}{2}$$
$$=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}=RHS$$

Comment: Yes I noticed it, just can't see how to "cancel" before factoring, not that clear to me